# Datagram Unix domain socket with Boost.Asio

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm struggling to receive data with a synchronous client code that is using datagram Unix sockets with Boost.Asio.

The server seems to be working fine because if I connect to it with *netcat* I receive data. However, when trying with the code below, it gets stuck in receive_from(). *strace* shows that the receive_from() system call is called but nothing is received, while *strace* on the server shows that is trying to send data to the client but it is failing to do so.

```
boost::asio::io_service io_service;

boost::asio::local::datagram_protocol::socket socket(io_service);
socket.open();

cmd::cmd cmd;
cmd.type = cmd::cmdtype::request;
cmd.id = cmd::cmdid::dumptop;

boost::asio::local::datagram_protocol::endpoint receiver_endpoint("socket.unix");

/* The server receives this data successfully */
socket.send_to(
    boost::asio::buffer(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&cmd), 
    sizeof(cmd)),
    receiver_endpoint
);

boost::array<char, 128> recv_buf;
boost::asio::local::datagram_protocol::endpoint ep;

/* When the server sends data, nothing is received here.
   Maybe it's an issue with the endpoint??? */
size_t len = socket.receive_from(
    boost::asio::buffer(recv_buf), ep);
```

Comment: It might be worth posting the relevant parts of the strace output, both from the client and the server.

Comment: There is no such as receive_from() system call. Did you mean recv(2)?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you've only set up the transmit side.

To also receive over the same socket, you will need to bind to a filename, just as you have on the server side.  Here's a modified version of the last few lines of your code:

```
boost::array<char, 128> recv_buf;
boost::asio::local::datagram_protocol::endpoint ep("socket.unix.client");
// bind to the previously created and opened socket:
socket.bind(ep);

/* now get data from the server */
size_t len = socket.receive_from(
    boost::asio::buffer(recv_buf), ep);
```

The usual idiom is that the server has a well-known file name (`socket.unix` in your code) and that each communicating client creates its own unique name by doing something like appending its own pid.  This example just uses `socket.unix.client` for simplicity  but of course that will limit you to exactly one client until you change it.